# Store session in client's browser using raw node.js and cookie without express

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, client

I am trying to store client session using raw node.js without express.

When a user logs in I have the username and password. Now, how to store a session in client browser using cookie. And how to identify the user when they refresh the tab or goes to another link.I don't want to use `client-sessions` module as I want to understand the approach.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I suggest you to watch  [everything about authentication in NodeJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvviEA1pOXw#t=32m10s) It explains cookies in a part very well.

You have to give the browser some data to hold for it to use later, which being `cookies`. Browser uses this **data** to show the server what kind of *authentications* it has processed *before* for the server and the user to proceed without repetition.

In node.js, using `client-sessions` module, you can set a cookie by calling

```
app.post('/login', function(req,res){
 User.findOne({password: req.body.userPassword}, function(err, user){

 if(user){
    req.session.user = user; //here you are setting the cookie for the client,
  }
})
})
```

You could also specify what kind of cookie you want to set by just adding it a property

```
 req.session.userEmail = user.email;
```

Now let's check how the server uses ***authentication***

```
app.get('/someUrl', function(req,res){

  if(req.session.user){
   console.log("user exists!");
  }

})
```

You can check what the client sends you by using `session` property of `req` object => **`req.session`**

To bind it with database you need to do,

```
  if(req.session.user){
     User.findOne({email: req.session.user.email}, func...)
  }
```

So basically, with each request that client sends, this procedure is used by the server to identify the cookies and to make the web-app user-friendly with no repetition.

It is like giving **every** student an **ID** in a school for authentication.

**Security**

For security, the node module `cookie-sessions` encrypt data automatically when we add `secret` attribute in `app.use()` function. Please see [using `secret` in client-sessions module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions)

Comment: in short, I have to store the username as a cookie in users browser and when they make another request i will get data about them from that cookie, right?

Comment: yes, not only username, you would also want to add **password** cookie for security @ImtiazChowdhury

Comment: but won't that cause security issues? should i hash or encrypt those data i store inside cookie since cookies can be created manually.

Comment: please check https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions . when you use `secret` attribute in `app.use()` function, it encrypts the data automatically.

Comment: thanks for your answer Mr. Delson. I hope it will solve my problem.

Comment: no problem, can you please set the question as answered, if you have more questions feel free to ask @ImtiazChowdhury

Comment: actually i wanted to do it in raw node.js without express as mentioned in the question. And i will surely do if it solves my difficulty. Thank You

Comment: Well you need to **create a server**  for client & server to *communicate*. You can use `http`, `express` or `router` too if you want

Comment: The youtube link is broken. :(